# How to sum each unique element of an array within an array

Tags: ruby

I have an array like:

```
[1, 84]
[11, 29]
[11, 84]
[12, 18]
[15, 55]
[15, 4]
```

I Want to generate a new array from this array like:

```
[1, 84, 1]
[11, 113, 2]
[12, 18, 1]
[15, 59, 2]
```

where the first element of the each sub-array will be unique and their corresponding second element will be sum, and the third element will be their count. In case of `11`, `29 + 84 = 113`, and `11` exists `2` times, so `[11, 113, 2]`.

Comment: Why, just out of curiosity?

Comment: No one point of time of a logic in my rails/ruby code needs to be work like in this way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a.group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k,v.map(&:last).inject(:+),v.size] }
# => [[1, 84, 1], [11, 113, 2], [12, 18, 1], [15, 59, 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [
  [1, 84],
  [11, 29],
  [11, 84],
  [12, 18],
  [15, 55],
  [15, 4]
]

a.group_by(&:first).values.map {|arys| [arys.first.first, arys.map{|a| a[1]}.inject(:+), arys.count]}
```